# html checkbox unclick hides function variables

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

I have checkboxes created with labels:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" />ATL6101</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" />ATL6102</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" />ATL6103</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" />ATL6104</label><br>
<label><input type="checkbox" />ATL6105</label><br>
```

This corresponds to a function variable.

```
Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', function () {


    getRoute('4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707', '822 RALPH MCGILL BLVD NE,30306', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Green', 'ATL6101');

    getRoute('4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707', '4575 WEBB BRIDGE RD,30005', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Lime', 'ATL6102');

    getRoute('4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707', '520 W PONCE DE LEON AVE,30030', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Maroon', 'ATL6103');

    getRoute('4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707', '575 OLYMPIC DR,30601', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Navy', 'ATL6104');

    getRoute('4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707', '3470 MCCLURE BRIDGE RD,30096', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Lime', 'ATL6105');




});
```

How can I say if the checkbox is not clicked ignore the function variable?
And is there a way I can replace the values in the function and dynamically create the checkboxes?

Comment: What is the actual purpose, i.e actual micro input and micro output, would you mind little bit elaborating it clearly what you need

Comment: I need to display multiple routes on one map. But I also need the ability to show all the maps or only 3/5, etc. I have the routes showing correctly on the map. Now I need to be able to add/remove the routes by using the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to dynamically generate checkboxs and call a function depending if that corresponding checkbox is selected.

To do that, you will need to have two variables.

- `routes` an object containing all the routes and the parameters associated. This object will be used to create the checkboxs.
- `selectedRoutes` an array containing the names of the currently selected routes. This will be used to only call `getRoute` on routes that are selected.

To create the checkboxs, you can make use of [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). Please folllow the MDN links for more info about this, or see my example below.

You need to make sure you capture the `click` event on each checkbox, to be able to syncronize the `selectedRoutes` variable with what the user selected. This is simply done by checking the checkbox `checked` attribute and adding / removing the checkbox `value` attribute into `selectedRoutes`.

With that, you are able to have the currently selected values in an array. To make use of it, you can have for example a button, and capture the `click` event. On the event, you only need to check who `routes` elements are selected by searching on the `selectedRoutes` array. If they are selected, you call the `getRoute` function using the parameters of that route.

```js
const content = document.getElementById('content');
const routes = {
  'ATL6101': ['4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707','822 RALPH MCGILL BLVD NE,30306','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','Green'],
  'ATL6102': ['4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707','4575 WEBB BRIDGE RD,30005','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','Lime'],
  'ATL6103': ['4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707','520 W PONCE DE LEON AVE,30030','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','Maroon'],
  'ATL6104': ['4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707','575 OLYMPIC DR,30601','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','Navy'],
  'ATL6105': ['4200 N COMMERCE DR,30344-5707','3470 MCCLURE BRIDGE RD,30096','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','Lime'],
};
let selectedRoutes = [];

for (routeValue in routes) {
  const label = document.createElement('label');
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  const text = document.createTextNode(routeValue);
  input.type = 'checkbox';
  input.value = routeValue;
  input.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      selectedRoutes.push(e.target.value);
    } else {
      selectedRoutes.splice(selectedRoutes.indexOf(e.target.value), 1);
    }
  });
  label.appendChild(input);
  label.appendChild(text);
  content.appendChild(label);
};

document.getElementById('action').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Directions', _ => {
    for (routeValue in routes) {
      // routeValue is not in selectedRoutes, ie route not selected by user
      if (!selectedRoutes.includes(routeValue)) continue;
      // add the original route name back in params
      const params = routes[routeValue].concat(routeValue);
      // actually call getRoute
      getRoute.apply(this, params);
    }
  });
});


// mocked implementations
const getRoute = console.log;
const Microsoft = {Maps: {loadModule: (x, y) => y()} };
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
<button id="action">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This looks really awesome and you answered the second part of my question beautifully. But I need to have the information in the function ignored if the box is not checked. If Route ATL6102 is not checked but ATL6101 and ATL6103 are checked the only routes that would appear on the map would be ATL6101 and ATL6103.

Comment: I don't understand. The behavior that you describe is what actually happens. `getRoute` is not called for elements that are not checked. If you have an issue with Microsoft Maps API, I suggest you open a new question so anyone can help with that.

Comment: I have placed the script containing the array before the </script> in the head of the html. I have placed the button div in the body of the html. I get the map with the routes and I get the click me button but nothing else. I have also tried copying the frame source you provided and although it works perfectly here if I paste it into Notepad++, save it as an html file and open it in Chrome I only get the checkboxs and click me button - no details on the route like you have above

Comment: Of course not, this isn't implementing Microsoft Maps. You can clearly see those functions are mocked. You need to integrate it with your existing codebase.

Comment: My problem was I failed to load snippet-javascript-console.min.js

Comment: I now get the error message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'getRoute' has already been declared". How would I get around that?

Comment: You need to delete the last two lines of my implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172128/discussion-between-jorjon-and-user974061).